# passing values to meteor partials

Tags: meteor

I'm learning meteor to build quick website prototypes.
I'm trying to understand how to generate a set of values to populate the site templates and partials.

I have a layout.html template

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <header role="banner">
      {{>site-header}}
    </header>
    <h1>This is {{siteLogo}}</h1>
    <main role="main">
      {{ yield }}
    </main>
    <footer role="contentinfo">
      {{> site-footer }}
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

in main.js I define the following:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Session.set('siteLogo', 'the logo');
});
Template.site-header.helpers({
  siteLogo: function(){ return Session.get('siteLogo'); }
});
Template.layout.helpers({
  siteLogo: function(){ return Session.get('siteLogo'); }
});
```

With this i can pass the value of siteLogo to layout.html.

I have a site-header.html partial

```
<template name="site-header">
  <h1>{{siteLogo}}</h1>
</template>
```

I can't seem to be able to pass the value of siteLogo to the partial. Is there a way to do that?
Is it necessary to create a Session variable to pre-fill some values or can i just create a json settings list  and access the value globally?

something that would go in main.js, like the yaml config file in a jekyll site:

```
siteSettings = [
   {
    siteLogo: "some brand name",
    otherValue: "something else"
   }
]
```

---

## update

---

I'm a bit confused, I'm must be doing something wrong.
I've created a quick new meteor app to test this.

I have main.html

```
<head>
  <title>handlebar-helper</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> header}}
  {{> hello}}
  {{> footer}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>

<template name="header">
  <header>
    <h1>{{ headline }}</h1>
    <p>tagline</p>
  </header>
</template>

<template name="footer">
  <footer role="contentinfo">
    <h1>{{ headline }}</h1>
    <small>copyright</small>
  </footer>
</template>
```

And main.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to handlebar-helper.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    Session.set('headline', 'My fancy headline');
  });
  Handlebars.registerHelper('headline', function(){
    return Session.get('headline');
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // server code here
}
```

And i can't still pass the value of `headline` into `>header` of `>footer`

if I try to put the `Session.set` into the `Meteor.isServer` block, I get a syntax error, `Session is not defined`

---

Cheers

Comment: the updated code has a typo - `Handlebars.regesterHelper()` is correct as in richsilv answer below.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I re-read it i don't know how many times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `Template.site-header.helpers` function declared for `siteLogo`?  If not it won't work - you can't use a helper from another template.  If you need to use `siteLogo` in a variety of places, it's best to use a [Handlebars block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html), as these can be accessed by any template.

**UPDATE**

The Handlebars helper would just look like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('siteLogo', function() {
   return Session.get('siteLogo');
});
```

However, if you've already got a `siteLogo` helper in the `site-header` Template, it suggests something else is wrong, like a typo in a template or helper name.  Is there an error in the console?

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to use a dictionary-style structure to store reactive data, you can do something like this:

```
Session.set('myDict', {foo: 1, bar: 2});

Handlebars.registerHelper('myDict', function(key) {
   return Session.get('myDict') ? Session.get('myDict')[key] : null;
});
```

And then use this in your template: `{{myDict 'foo'}}`.  Obviously, the format above would work fine in a tempate helper as well, but it would only be accessible from within that template.  The ternary operator is just to check that `myDict` has been initialised before it lets a template try to look up one of the keys, which is a common Meteor problem on page load.

Incidentally, if you're finding Session variables a cumbersome way to deal with reactive dictionary-like data structures, it's pretty easy to roll your own.  [This](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source) is the best introduction.

Comment: I've added a Template.site-header.helpers. But it's still not rendering the value in the partial. So I'm not sure i understand. Would you have an example of the Handlebars block method? cheers

Comment: quick question—now that it's working— do I have to initiate every variable like this individually, or is it possible to generate a json list and get the key: values pair?

Comment: Updated again in response to your last question.

Comment: Thanks for that! This is really helpful. I will have a look the the video link. I've tried to add a nested value (phone: {human: ' 01 01 01 01 01', machine: '00441010101}) then access it via {{ myDict 'phone.human'} it of course doesn't work. is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible if you update the helper function.  Just split the string by `.` and then do a recursive lookup using the resulting array, returning null if it encounters a null/undefined at any stage, or else returning the last lookup value.